# Google automl translate with tags

Tags: google-cloud-automl, automl

I have created a custom Model with Google AutoML. And I would like to use some "tags" such has  and make sure it doesn't get translated by Google AutoML. I expect that these tags would be copied as is in the target language at the corresponding place. `

Is there such a feature? I didn't find anything in their documentation.

Example:

The dog is walking `<tag>` outside.  --- >  Le chien marche `<tag>` dehors.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "tags"? On your example, which one is the "tag"? What is the current output of your model when you do prediction? Are you using AutoML Translate under Vertex AI or just AutoML Translate?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the example.. the tags were not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.

You first need to specify "text/html" as mime_type in your request.

And you need to put any text you want to keep as is between these tags:
(you can use any of the two ways)

```
<span translate="no">Your text</span>

<span class="notranslate">Your text</span>
```